# MySQL checking last updated time on multiple devices

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to check the last update date and time (recordTime) for every treehugger id (TreeHuggerId) and below is what I did. The output was not the last update time according to the below query. Please advice. Thank you.

```
 SELECT `recordTime`, DISTINCT `TreeHuggerId` FROM `SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS`
 WHERE `TreeHuggerId` < 20000 and `TreeHuggerId` > 10000
 ORDER BY `recordTime` desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select `MAX(recordTime)` for every `TreeHuggerId` for that and you don't need distinct

```
SELECT TreeHuggerId,MAX(recordTime) FROM SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS
```

Then at the end

```
GROUP BY TreeHuggerId
```

Like this

```
SELECT TreeHuggerId,MAX(recordTime) FROM SENSOR_TREEHUGGERS
WHERE TreeHuggerId BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000
GROUP BY TreeHuggerId
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Hanky, when to use Distinct and Group By?

Comment: When you need to see 1 guy only once and with some aggregate information about him from other fields

Comment: ohh so 2 guys and above should use `Group By`

Comment: If one guy has more than 1 records and you need to see him only once with some other aggregate info, for example number of records then you group by that field. If everyone has only 1 record then you don't need to group